# How to mock annotated private EJB field

Tags: java, ejb

Im struggling with following problem:

1. In our "underTest" Class we have  following field:

```
@EJB
private Transformer transformer;
```

2. Method which I want to test calls this `transformer`:

```
 public void writeMessage(Message message) {
        String txtMessage = transformer.transformMessage(message);
        }
```

I want to mock `Transformer` class and whenever it calls `transformMessage` it will return some String, eg. "test123"

I've already tried to use:

```
    @InjectMocks
    private UnderTest underTest = new UnderTest();
    
    @Mock
    private Transformer transformer;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        underTest .setTransformer(transformer);
    }
```

And then:

```
Mockito.when(underTest.transform(message)).thenReturn("test123")
```

But I keep getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" in method transform.

We don't have PowerMockito in our Project, same as Spring.

Comment: knittl has provided the right answer. Your original line actually has _two_ problems. One is using Mockito on something that isn't a mock. That should have triggered a different error, but `underTest.transform` is actually _called_, and that triggers the NPE first. If `underTest` would have been spied, the correct usage would have been `doReturn("test123").when(underTest).transform(message)`, as that will not call the actual `transform` message.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `Mockito.when(underTest.transform(message)).thenReturn("test123")`, then Mockito must call `underTest.transform(message)`, which is a real method call (because Java is eagerly evaluated) *on your class under test*. But you should setup your *mock* instead, not the class under test. You want:

```
Mockito.when(transformer.transformMessage(anyString()))
        .thenReturn("test123");
```